# Manipulating static resources in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am learning C#, WPF and XAML and at this point I am targeting internationalization of the product.

I can define the string that I want to translate in Resources.resx, and I would like to be able to manipulate the strings when I use them in my XAML files. Let's make an example, supposing to have a label like this

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="{x:Static p:Resources.username}" />
```

In Resources.resx I define name `username` with value `username` and the label gets the correct value.

Suppose now that I want to display another label, but this time I want to display the text `Username`, with capital u. The immediate solution would be defining name `Username` value `Username`, but I am getting a duplicated resource. In other templating systems, such as in django, I can use the initial resource and and I can apply a filter to modify the string, but I am not able to achieve this in C#.

Is there a way to manypulate static resources in C# and XAML, for example to apply a converter that capitalizes the first letter of the string?

Comment: It's often better to use resource dictionaries for different languages. You define one for each, start with say the english one merged. Merge in whichever one is appropriate for non english language. These have entries with the same key for each given word so there's one with x:Key="username" in each. Use dynamicresource on your value for label content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Binding` has a `Converter` property. So you can do bind to the static resource and use a converter to modify the value:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StrToLowerValueConverter x:Key="strToLowerCnv"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Resources.username}, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource strToLowerCnv}}" />
```

And the converter itself:

```
public class StrToLowerValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value as string)?.ToLower() ?? value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```